# Using std::string fails Signals and Slots

Tags: c++, qt

Both of my signal and slots have a `std::string` type parameter. My signal is in class b and slot in class A. If i change the parameter type to int the signal works but fails with a std::string.Any suggestions on how I could resolve this issue ?

Here is the code that I use

```
connect(this,SIGNAL(SignalB(std::string)),ClassA::PtrClassA,SLOT(MethodA(std::string)));
```

Comment: It should work with `std::string` as well. Could you post the code for signal and slot you are using?

Comment: Have you registered std::string as a meta type?

Comment: @RobbieE How do I register it as a meta type ?

Comment: Post the error message, please

Comment: metatype registration is only needed for queued connections. If both QObjects live in the same thread, the default is direct, so no registration needed.

Comment: Why not convert it to QString?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using queued connections, you need to register `std::string` as meta type. Use `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(std::string)` in one of your headers. Call `qRegisterMetaType<std::string>();` in the initialization of your code.

See [QMetaType docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetatype.html#details) for more information.

Comment: This answer, as you present it is wrong, because this 'magic' is not always useful. From your docs: "The class is used as a helper to marshall types in QVariant and in **queued** signals and slots connections."

Comment: @Riateche Thanks that worked. Do we need to do `qRegisterMetaType<std::string>("std::string");` in constructor of every class where i am setting a connection of a signal to a slot ?

Comment: No, you need to call it once for entire app.

Comment: Nitpick: avoid to use the `qRegisterMetaType` overload which takes a string parameter, use instead `qRegisterMetaType<std::string>()`.

Comment: It's strange for C++ coder, but Qt signals works only for fully qualified types. For example `using namespace std; … SIGNAL(SignalB(string))` will never work, but compiles fine!