# Create Thread in QDialog and emit signals to QDialog in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

I created an application that has a mainwindow and from this window creates a QDialog. This QDialog should create a RenderThread that emits received images from the camera or in the example emits text. When i debug this it seems that the connection is never made as adding a breakpoint in the slot `CameraWindow::debugSomething` does not get caught. Whats wrong ?
I followed this example: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-mandelbrot.html but it seems that i've done something wrong.

```
qtDEVC::qtDEVC(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
    : QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    connect (ui.pushButton_startCam, SIGNAL( clicked() ),this,SLOT( startCam() ) );

    /**Threading*/
    CameraWindow camWindow = new CameraWindow(this);
}


int qtDEVC::startCam()
{
    camWindow.show();
    camWindow.startCaptureThread();
}
```

CameraWindow Class:

```
 CameraWindow::CameraWindow(QWidget *parent)
        : QDialog(parent)
    {
    ui.setupUi(this);

    connect(&thread, SIGNAL(sendText(std::string)),
        this, SLOT(debugSomething(std::string)));
}

void CameraWindow::debugSomething(std::string something){
    QString somethings(something.c_str());
qDebug()<<somethings;
}

int CameraWindow::startCaptureThread(){

    RenderThread *thread = new RenderThread(this, guid, CLEYE_COLOR_RAW, CLEYE_VGA, 50); 

    thread->StartCapture(); //starts thread in low priority and sets _running to true
}
```

CameraWindow header

```
 class CameraWindow : public QDialog
 {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
    CameraWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~CameraWindow();
    Ui::CameraWindow ui;

public slots:
    int startCaptureThread();
    void debugSomething(QString);

private:
    RenderThread thread;
};
```

RenderThread Class

```
 void RenderThread::run()
 {

    // image capturing loop
    while(_running)
    {
    qDebug()<<("render while()"); //is printed with qdebug correctly
    if (restart)
        break;
           if (abort)
               return;

    qDebug("it");  //is also printed with qdebug correctly

    emit sendText(text);
}
```

RenderThread header

```
class RenderThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    RenderThread(QObject *parent, GUID cameraGUID, CLEyeCameraColorMode mode, CLEyeCameraResolution resolution, float fps);
    RenderThread();
    ~RenderThread();

    bool StartCapture();

signals:

    void sendText(QString &text);

protected: 
    void run();

private:
    QMutex mutex;
    QWaitCondition condition;
    //some more private variables for construction
```

};

I think that this creation seems somehow wrong: `RenderThread *thread = new RenderThread(this);`

Comment: Set connection parameter as QString, instead of  std::string.

Comment: Register std::string as meta type. Please check similar SO[Using std::string fails Signals and Slots][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121554/using-stdstring-fails-signals-and-slots

Comment: Changing to QString has no effect

Comment: what is the runtime error?

Comment: there is none it is just not emitting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that's worrying about the question is the word "RenderThread". Note that Qt only allows rendering on the main thread. You can create separate threads for calculations of image data, but whenever you use a painter and draw objects, that must happen on the main thread. However, If you're just going to capture the image and pass that to the main thread, via signals and slots, then that should be ok.

Secondly, whilst you've not shown all your code, I'm assuming from the function called RenderThread::run() and from the Qt example that you may have inherited from QThread here. If this is the case, please note that this is not how to use QThread. Instead, you should have your class inherit from QObject and move that to a QThread. You can read about how to [use QThread properly here](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/).

I know it's a Qt example that you've followed, but even the guys at Qt think it's a bad idea. [Here's an article](http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/) of how to really use QThreads.

With that in mind, here's an outline of how I would use QThread for this: -

```
class CameraWindow : public QDialog
{
    private:
      CameraObject* m_pCamObject;
};

class CameraObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:

    private slots:
         startCaptureThread();

    private:
};

int CameraWindow::startCaptureThread()
{
     m_pCamObject = new CameraObject;

     QThread* pThread = new QThread;

     this->moveToThread(pThread); // CameraObject will run on the new thread

     connect(pThread, SIGNAL(started()), m_pCamObject, SLOT(startCaptureThread()));
     connect(pThread, SIGNAL(finished()), pThread, SLOT(deleteLater()); // clear up when
```

finished

```
     pThread->start();
}
```

Note that here is a CameraObject, separated from the CameraWindow. The QThread is just a controller of the thread and keeps a clean separation from the CameraObject.

Another reason for handling threads this way is that you can move multiple QObject instances to the new thread, rather than always creating a new thread per object. If you've more threads than CPU cores, you're unlikely to gain by creating yet another thread.

Comment: `thread->StartCapture();` //starts thread in low priority and sets _running to true. i read already that there is confusions with using threads but the fact is that i cannont emit this signal and need to get it to work. i'm a beginner with qt and willing to learn but at the moment i need to get this to work ;) naming the class "RenderThread" is based on the example and gets renamed after I'm sure i do not have to spend my time on setting up a different infrastructure then the one provided by QT

Comment: i guess i got what you mean, thank you very much for your advice. on a scale from 1 to 10 how sure are you this will work because its my 3rd try with provided qt infrastructure to get this to work which gives threading in qt a very poor grade i guess...why is it not working as in the provided example ?

Comment: If you code it properly according to using QThreads without inheriting from them, then it will work, assuming you've made the correct connections. As I said, the developers of Qt claim state that various examples use QThreads by inheritance, but it's being abused. QThread is a thread management class, so should only be inherited if you need to rewrite the handling of the underlying threading mechanism.

Comment: so i guess there is no 1line solution for this problem and i need to u-turn which is bad because these were just were brief snippeds of all the code i wrote so far..

Comment: Yes, It's not 1 line, but it's not much more. If you have a QObject based item to place on another thread, there are really just 3 lines to get it working. Create the thread, move the object to the thread, call thread->start(). Everything else is handling connections and what you want the QObject to do.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of CameraWindow class, you are connecting a RenderThread's signal but it is not the same object which is started in startCaptureThread. Change your startCaptureThread like this:

```
int CameraWindow::startCaptureThread()
{
    thread.StartCapture(); //starts thread in low priority and sets _running to true
}
```

In this method, the thread member of CameraWindow is started.

P.S.: post the headers too, we can't see the members from this code.

Comment: i get [error C2228](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/3y365xw6%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) doing this. i'll post the headers

Answer (score -1):

In the mentioned example, `CameraWindow` class holds a `RenderThread thread` variable, not a `RenderThread *thread`.

You are connecting a pointer address in your connect call:

```
connect(&thread, SIGNAL(sendText(std::string)),
    this, SLOT(debugSomething(std::string)));
```

Try to use a good address:

```
connect(thread, SIGNAL(sendText(std::string)),
    this, SLOT(debugSomething(std::string)));
```

This is not a tested answer.

Comment: connect call takes pointers as argument so there is nothing wrong with his connect call.