# Display QMessageBox at end of inline thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I am a novice at Qt, and am struggling to get a simple slot/signal to work.

In my Qt app, I have a long running task that begins when I press a button. In order to keep the gui responsive, I start this work in a thread. When the thread finishes its task, I want it to display a message box. I first tried to show the message box in my thread, but quickly found this is only allowed from the gui thread. I then attempted to emit a signal at the end of the thread to signify that the messagebox should pop up but the corresponding slot is never called.

```
//MainWindow.h:
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "myclass.h"


namespace Ui {
   class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
void on_my_button_clicked();
void handleComplete(std::string endMsg);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    MyClass mymember;
    std::thread myThread;
};




// MainWindow.cpp
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QWidget::setWindowFlags(Qt::CustomizeWindowHint);

    connect(&mymember, &MyClass::workComplete, this, &MainWindow::handleComplete);
}

void MainWindow::on_my_button_clicked() {
    myThread = std::thread([&] {
            std::string endMsg = mymember.DoWork();
            emit mymember.workComplete(endMsg);
            //QMessageBox::information(this, "Work Complete", QString::fromStdString(endMsg)); // first attempt
    });
}

void MainWindow::handleComplete(std::string endMsg){
    QMessageBox::information(this, "Work Complete", QString::fromStdString(endMsg));
}
```

MyClass inherits from QObject, contains the QObject macro, and has a signal defined `void workComplete(std::string endmsg);`

How can I get the message box to pop at the end of the thread (preferably without emitting the signal within the `MyClass.DoWork()` method) ?

EDIT::

```
//myclass.h
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

signals:
    void workComplete(std::string endMsg);
public:
    std::string DoWork();

};
```

Comment: show MyClass code.

Comment: @eyllanesc, added. My myclass.cpp has the implementation of `DoWork()` (obviously) but nothing regarding the `workComplete` signal. Do I need to implement something else regarding that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using std::string fails Signals and Slots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121554/using-stdstring-fails-signals-and-slots)

Comment: The problem is caused because you are using `std::string` and this is not registered, a possible solution is that you use the solution of the duplicate question or use `QString` instead of `std::string`, When I replicated your code I got the following error message: *QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'std::string'
(Make sure 'std::string' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
terminate called without an active exception**